# Fetch all Images from Android Photo Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to fetch all images in my application from android photo gallery .because I want to load an image into my application again after saving it into android gallery .
For Saving my image into gallery I use below method.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ContentResolverObj, bitMap, "uniqueTitle", "description");
```

Now programatically I want to fetch all images into my application and want to get above saved image on the basis of tile.Two questions here.
1st:Can I fetch all images from photo gallery of android ?
2nd:can I read single photo detail like title etc after fetching it.

Comment: Hi RajaReddy P :thanks you so much great guide.one thing here how can I get title or any unique key with that I can identify that image? I see I can read the ID of image . So at time of saving image using my above line of code I can set its ID ?

Answer (score 1):

by using this code i am able to display phone gallery images in gridview, depending on your requirement change this..

```
public class MyPhoneGallery extends Activity  {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  private Cursor imagecursor, actualimagecursor;
  private int image_column_index, actual_image_column_index;
  GridView imagegrid;
  private int count;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
        init_phone_image_grid();
  }
  private void init_phone_image_grid() {
        String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
        imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
        image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        count = imagecursor.getCount(); 
        imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

              System.gc();
              String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
              actualimagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,null, null, null);
              actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
              actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
              String i = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
              System.gc();
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
              intent.putExtra("filename", i);
              startActivity(intent);

           }
      });
  }

  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
              mContext = c;
         }
        public int mygetItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        public int getCount() {
              return count;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
              return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
              return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
              System.gc();
              ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
              if (convertView == null) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                    i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
                    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(125, 125));
              }
              else {
                    i = (ImageView) convertView;
              }
              return i;
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and got image, maybe it works for you

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
imagecursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);

int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
ids = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
```

You can find adapter code gridview and setadapter from below URL
[source code for adapter and gridview](http://iandroiddeveloperphotogallery.blogspot.in/)