# android gallery: fetch id of all images

Tags: android, image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetch all Images from Android Photo Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121690/fetch-all-images-from-android-photo-gallery)

I want to fetch id of all images from gallery and then store it in integer array.I found a code where I can get id of image after clicking on it but I don't want to do this way. I want to fetch id of all images without clicking on images and then store it in integer array.Please somebody help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the content resolver:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {ImageColumns._ID}, null, null,null);
```

And then form the int array using tha data obtained in this cursor.

```
if ((cur != null) && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        int[] idsArray = new int[cur.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            idsArray[i] = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns._ID));
            cur.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    cur.close();
```

Edit:

```
final Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(CameraConstants.IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH_EXTERNAL, null, null, null, ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
    final ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if ((cur != null) && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        final int count = cur.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            urlList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA));
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Then use urlList as follows:

```
for(String imageUrl: urlList){
 final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream is = null;
    is = new FileInputStream(new File(imageUrl));

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
 int width = options.outWidth;
 int height = options.outHeight
```

}

Comment: I am still not able to get images id through this. Please specify how to form int array using this data?? please help me out.

Comment: thanks!! @Vicky. Problem is solved now.

Comment: ur welcome!! PS: u could mark this answer correct if it worked.. ;)

Comment: how to use getHeight() and getWidth() method?? as I want to apply getHeight() and getWidth method in my code using id of gallery images.Here is my code

Comment: for (int imageId : mImageIds) {
        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageId);
           int width = originalImage.getWidth();
           int height = originalImage.getHeight();
     }

Comment: it gives me null pointer exception

Comment: for what u wanna u'll need not ids but data. See edited code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] projection = new String[] { ImageColumns._ID,
                    ImageColumns.TITLE, ImageColumns.DATA,
                    ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE, ImageColumns.SIZE };
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, null, null, null);
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    //fill data
}
```

I've also included other fields that might be of interest.

Comment: I am still not able to get images id through this. Please specify how to form int array using this data?? please help me out